# Can you style Tkinter GUIs with CSS?

Tags: python, css, tkinter

If not a built-in feature, is there an add-on package that allows Python's Tkinter to use CSS?

Comment: Try [tkstylesheet](https://pypi.org/project/tkstylesheet/), it doesn't use CSS but a custom simple stylesheet language. You can read the [documentation](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkStyleSheet/blob/master/Documentation.md) and [examples](https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkStyleSheet/tree/master/Examples) .

Answer (score 7):

There are no options to style it the same way if you could use CSS.

This documentation will help for Tkinter styling:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm

Comment: I recently reported to their bug tracker to consider this - at the least to support the same (limited) subset that gtk3 supports, e. g. margin, padding, border, colours. It would be nice if they could all support at the least the basic CSS rules, as an additional option. That way people could simply re-use CSS files on an ad-hoc basis to re-style anything they want to.

Answer (score -2):

There is a method with which you can style your window that uses a similar premise as CSS. I found this site to be quite helpful: [Options DB file](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-May/268518.html)

This method basically allows you to write all the default widget style configurations in a file, and then make a reference to that file in the .py file, and then load the preferences. This can be used when you want to be able to change the theme at runtime without having to have programmatically set them up. I myself am using it to enable different themes to be set up by the user and then load them at runtime dependant on the user (sign in, not logged into the system)