# Add notebook-like horizontal lines to text area tkinter

Tags: python, css, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to write a notebook in Python tkinter, I can't figure out how to add horizontal lines into the editable text area to make it look like a real textbook as I am new to this, I know how to do it in css but also can't figure out how to embed the css into the python. Any help will be appreciated

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

horborder_ = Frame(root, height=25, background='khaki')
horborder_.pack(expand='no', fill='x')

lineNum_ = Text(root, width=4, padx=3, border=0, background='khaki', state='disabled', wrap='none')
lineNum_.pack(side='left', fill='y')

textar_ = Text(root, wrap='word')
textar_.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you cannot embed css within tkinter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520492/can-i-style-my-tkinter-guis-the-way-you-style-html-with-css

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: you can add horizontal lines ,but they won't be in the background, they will take up one line of the widget and will scroll like anything else. While the image can look exactly like a line, the behavior will be exactly like if someone just typed `"----------------"`. Is that ok?